# How can I disable the preloading in a viewpager?

Tags: android, android-viewpager

How can I disable the preloading in a viewpager?.

I have a viewpager with 3 pages. So i dont want load the next page and previously page. How can i disable that behavior?

Comment: Good question! I also want to know if it's possible to load only one page at first and then cache other loaded pages.

Answer (score 11):

> How can I disable the preloading in a ViewPager?.

it is not possible. ViewPager preloads always at least 1 page. If you don't want this behaviour you should not use the ViewPager. You could use, for instance, a `RecyclerView`

*Old answer*

you have to call [setOffscreenPageLimit(1)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html#setOffscreenPageLimit%28int%29)

From the doc

> Set the number of pages that should be retained to either side of the
>   current page in the view hierarchy in an idle state. Pages beyond this
>   limit will be recreated from the adapter when needed.

Comment: Thank you! =D
But OffscreenPageLimit(0) don't work because the minimum value of the parameters is 1. 

OffscreenPageLimit(0) throws a log in the logcat

Comment: I hope this is because the 1 page is the actual page on display. It's sad that I need to do this because android keeps changing GUI elements on the wrong page and I'm using fragments in a ViewPager so everything has to be static to avoid OutOfMemory. I hope Android just throws out the entire GUI library at some point and starts over from scratch, everything is just awful now. I have an 800 line fragment now to be able to display maybe 15 dynamic elements.

Comment: Solution provided does not answer question.  The original question is how to disable preloading in a ViewPager (i.e. do not load next or previous page).  The solution provided does nothing as it assigns the default value of 1.

Answer (score 7):

Well, it seems like it's a bit more complicated than one would think.
The code below is an abstract class that should be implemented by your fragment. 
In fact it requires the  following:

1. Replace *onActivityCreated* with the *lazyOnActivityCreated*.
2. Implement the *lazyLoadData* method that loads the data for the tab.
3. After you have loaded the data or for any reason you have changed the active data call *setTabDataId*.

I know it sound a bit complicated but it works every time and will definitely work when *setUserHint* is no good.

Here is the abstract class:

```
public abstract class LazyFetchTabFragment extends AbstractTabFragment {

private String tabDataId;
private String activeTabDataId;

private boolean isActive = false;
private boolean isCreated = false;

@Override
public void onStop(){
    super.onStop();
    isCreated = false;
    activeTabDataId = null;
}

/**
 * An abstract method that should be called instead of {@link android.app.Fragment#onActivityCreated(Bundle)}.
 */
public abstract void lazyOnActivityCreated() throws Exception;
public abstract void lazyLoadData() throws Exception;

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

    try {
        lazyOnActivityCreated();
        isCreated = true;
        loadData();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e(this.getClass().getCanonicalName() + " - "
                + Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace()[2].getMethodName(), e.toString());
    }
}

@Override
public void setUserVisibleHint(boolean isVisibleToUser) {
    super.setUserVisibleHint(isVisibleToUser);
    // When changing tabs the spinner setOnItemSelectedListener is not called,
    // so use code below to trigger loading data.
    isActive = isVisibleToUser;
    loadData();
}

private void loadData(boolean force) {
    if (isActive && isCreated && tabDataId != null &&
            (force || (activeTabDataId == null || !activeTabDataId.equals(tabDataId))))
        try {
            lazyLoadData();
            activeTabDataId = tabDataId;
        } catch (Exception ex){
            Log.e(this.getClass().getCanonicalName() + " - "
                    + Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace()[2].getMethodName(), ex.toString());
        }
}

public void setTabDataId(String tabDataId) {
    this.tabDataId = tabDataId;
}
```

Good luck!

Comment: This methods gives NPE because sometimes it get's called before the `onCreateView`. Can you handle that??

Comment: I had to fully replace the answer, as it was not working properly. It will work properly now. I know it needs some polishing, but will probably help you for now!

Answer (score 1):

I modify the ViewPager source code

```
private static final int DEFAULT_OFFSCREEN_PAGES = 0;
```

You can find the source in ViewPager about `setOffscreenPageLimit`

```
public void setOffscreenPageLimit(int limit) {
    if (limit < DEFAULT_OFFSCREEN_PAGES) {
        Log.w(TAG, "Requested offscreen page limit " + limit + " too small; defaulting to " +
                DEFAULT_OFFSCREEN_PAGES);
        limit = DEFAULT_OFFSCREEN_PAGES;
    }
    if (limit != mOffscreenPageLimit) {
        mOffscreenPageLimit = limit;
        populate();
    }
}
```

Comment: Change the source code of what? The API itself? And how will it work when installed to a device that has the original untouched API?

Comment: @ichalos Usually using this approach you basically create ModifiedViewPager which you further use instead of ViewPager - and it works fine. Modification suggested by does not work though.